# Как получить в консоли только последний результат выполнения цикла for?

Tags: javascript, массивы, for

**Необходимо получить результат последней итерации цикла `for`**

```
const arraySuccess = []
const pages = Number(document.querySelector('.page') + 1
for (let i = 1; i < pages; i++) {
async function getResponse() {
const href = document.location.href
const urlResponse = `${href}&page=${i}`
const urlRequest = await fetch(urlResponse)
const requestBody = await urlRequest.text()
const parser = new DOMParser()
const outer = parser.parseFromString(requestBody, "text/html")
const takeSuccess = Array.from(outer.querySelectorAll('.success'))
arraySuccess.push(takeSuccess)
} getResponse()
```

Этот код выведет в консоль столько логов, сколько страниц в документе, мне необходимо получит только лишь конечный результат, с помощью метода `.push` я добавляю на каждой итерации элемент в массив, но при этом из-за области видимости цикла, я не могу получить весь массив как конечный результат, то есть если я вне цикла выведу `console.log(arraySuccess)` я получу все тот же пустой массив, даже если буду устанавливать задержку, он не успевает запушить прежде чем лог запустится. Мне необходимо получить в консоль результат конечной итерации цикла, то есть чтобы все эти `'.reviews-success'` были в одном массиве `arraySuccess`

P.S пагинация на сайте реализована с помощью `href` и необходимо поочередно выполнять запросы.

Comment: _при этом из-за области видимости цикла, я не могу получить весь массив как конечный результат_ - это неверное утверждение. В приведенном, неполном(sic!), куске кода в цикле просто объявляется функция. Неизвестно что с ней происходит, скорее всего она даже не вызывается. Очевидно, что в этом случае arraySuccess останется пустым

Comment: Что интересно, первый блок кода абсолютно никак не связан с вопросом и в текущем виде только мешает понять суть вопроса.

Comment: @Grundy снова приветствую! Я первый код привел чтобы было проще понять какой конечный результат я хочу получить, в моем примере точно так же нужно просто получить последнее значение всего цикла, это будет решением моего вопроса по-сути, забыл добавить вывод функции, исправил )

Comment: Существенная разница в том, что в твоем цикле функция асинхронная, а в первом блоке - синхронная. Из-за этого ответы абсолютно разные будут.

Comment: @Grundy это да, это я не указал, но сама суть остается той же, на последней итерации нужное мне значение )

Comment: Нет не той же. Почему-то во втором блоке ты догадался добавлять в массив, а в первом просто выводишь `console.log`. Фактически ты сам усложняешь задачу, давая код, который не связан с реальной задачей

Comment: @Grundy я удалил чтобы не отвлекало

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В данном случае не происходит ожидание завершения асинхронной функции, поэтому цикл завершается до того, как выполнятся все запросы.

Вместо этого достаточно было использовать `await` и вернуть из функции результат:

1. сделать функцию глобальной и принимающей номер страницы как параметр:

   ```
   async function getResponse(i) {
      const href = document.location.href
      const urlResponse = `${href}&page=${i}`
      const urlRequest = await fetch(urlResponse)
      const requestBody = await urlRequest.text()
      const parser = new DOMParser()
      const outer = parser.parseFromString(requestBody, "text/html")
      const takeSuccess = Array.from(outer.querySelectorAll('.success'))
      return takeSuccess  
   }
   ```
2. цикл становится следующим

   ```
   for (let i = 1; i < pages; i++) {
      arraySuccess.push(await getResponse(i))
   }
   ```

Comment: Ответ есть, но не совсем конечный результат, получил в итоге массив из двух массивов )

Comment: @Apache207, результат тот же, что ты получил бы если бы операция была синхронная ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯ если нужен плоский список, просто используй `spread`:  `.push(...await getResponse(i))`

Comment: это полностью решило мой вопрос! Огромное Вам спасибо!